# GetWindowThreadProcessId() IAT hooking: How compare "dwProcessID" parameter?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, api-hook

I'm hooking [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) with sucess using the following code.

Now i want check if **dwProcessID** parameter corresponds to id of determinated process and in positive case prevent execute original function:

```
Result := OldGetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, dwProcessID);
```

I tried this, but not worked:

```
if dwProcessID = 12345 then exit;
```

Here is my complete code:

```
library MyLIB;

uses
  Windows,
  ImageHlp;

{$R *.res}

type
  PGetWindowThreadProcessId = function(hWnd: THandle; dwProcessID: DWord)
    : DWord; stdcall;

var
  OldGetWindowThreadProcessId: PGetWindowThreadProcessId;

function HookGetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd: THandle; dwProcessID: DWord)
  : DWord; stdcall;

begin
  try
    // Check if is some process
  except
    MessageBox(0, 'Error', 'HookGetWindowThreadProcessId Error', 0);
  end;
  Result := OldGetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, dwProcessID);
end;

procedure PatchIAT(strMod: PAnsichar; Alt, Neu: Pointer);
var
  pImportDir: pImage_Import_Descriptor;
  size: CardinaL;
  Base: CardinaL;
  pThunk: PDWORD;
begin
  Base := GetModuleHandle(nil);
  pImportDir := ImageDirectoryEntryToData(Pointer(Base), True,
    IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT, size);
  while pImportDir^.Name <> 0 Do
  begin
    If (lstrcmpiA(PAnsichar(pImportDir^.Name + Base), strMod) = 0) then
    begin
      pThunk := PDWORD(Base + pImportDir^.FirstThunk);
      While pThunk^ <> 0 Do
      begin
        if DWord(Alt) = pThunk^ Then
        begin
          pThunk^ := CardinaL(Neu);
        end;
        Inc(pThunk);
      end;
    end;
    Inc(pImportDir);
  end;
end;

procedure DllMain(reason: Integer);

begin
  case reason of
    DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      begin
        OldGetWindowThreadProcessId := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(user32),
          'GetWindowThreadProcessId');

        PatchIAT(user32, GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(user32),
          'GetWindowThreadProcessId'), @HookGetWindowThreadProcessId);

      end;
    DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
      begin
      end;
  end;
end;

begin
  DllProc := @DllMain;
  DllProc(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PGetWindowThreadProcessId` type and `HookGetWindowThreadProcessId()` function are both declaring the `dwProcessID` parameter incorrectly.  It is an output parameter, so it needs to be declared as either `var dwProcessID: DWord` or as `dwProcessID: PDWord`.

And then you need to call `OldGetWindowThreadProcessId()` to retrieve the actual PID before you can then compare it to anything.  So your requirement of "*in positive case prevent execute original function*" is not realistic, because you need to execute the original function in order to determine the `dwProcessID` value to compare with.

Try this instead:

```
type
  PGetWindowThreadProcessId = function(hWnd: THandle; var dwProcessID: DWord): DWord; stdcall;

...

function HookGetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd: THandle; var dwProcessID: DWord): DWord; stdcall;
begin
  Result := OldGetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, dwProcessID);
  try
    if dwProcessID = ... then
      ...
  except
    MessageBox(0, 'Error', 'HookGetWindowThreadProcessId Error', 0);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: OK, thank you. But based in example of the last answer [see here](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=51927), seems that `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` still is returning **thread id** and **pid** of process that i'm comparing, i have a `Exit()` after comparation. Why this is happening?

Comment: Because the hook code above is calling the **original** `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` and returns whatever the original returns. What do you WANT to happen instead? Perhaps you are looking for something like this? `Result := OldGetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, dwProcessID); if dwProcessID = ... then begin dwProcessID := 0; Result := 0; Exit; end;`